# missing items from python lists

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I have two functions that generates two matrices, the first function generate some square matrix, while the second one generate a 1D matrix depending on the first matrix. Both functions depend on parameter N, the second function matrix result should have a matrix with (N*2)**2 .My problem is when i use a value of the parameter N grater than 4 their is always 10 missing elements from the second function result.(The OP functions have been deleted to create a minimal question. Check the edit for details. An example function is below demonstrating the issue

```py
def test(N):
        m = []
        for i in range(0,(N*2)):
            for j in range(-1,(N*7),4):
                m.append((i,j))


        return len(m)
```

example for N = 4

```
test(4)
```

Output:
64

example for N = 5

```
test(5)
```

Output:
90

The result in example 2 is 90 while it should be 100, can anyone help please

Comment: range stops one below the end.  Would this be the cause?

Comment: i thought about this but it runs smoothly for small number of N

Comment: it almost certainly related.  you only see it above 4 because you are counting by 4. For example, if you do `for j in range(-1,(N*7)+1,4)`, then it works correctly for `N=5`, but that doesn't fix it for all Ns.

Comment: yup now it works fins, i changed the range formula to this range(-1,(N*7)+(N-4),4)) and now it works realy fine

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check how many iterations either range will cause:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> len(range(0, n*2))
10
>>> len(range(-1, n*7, 4))
9
```

10*9 is indeed a total of 90 iterations and 90 elements added to the array.

I'm assuming you expect more elements from the inner loop, so probably you are confused about how `range` treats boundaries. The quick solution is to try variations like `n*7+1` until you get the correct behavior.